# Keycloak provider does not work when using Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, keycloak

When converting **Keycloak** sample authentication provider (Secret question authenticator) from `Java` to `Kotlin`, the **plugin does not work any more**. When deploying the `Jar` file, `log` raises odd errors such as bad signature. As far as I struggled, **the problem is Kotlin runtime libraries**. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Kotlin has dependencies (Kotlin StdLib or AKA Kotlin runtime).
Despite many documents and answers, the solution is not making a (So-called) Fat JAR by famous lines below gradle build script. The right way to resolve dependencies is to add them as WildFly (JBoss) modules using CLI or manual method.

```
module add --name=org.jetbrains.kotlin --dependencies=org.jetbrains --resources=<path-to-jar-file>
module add --name=org.jetrains --rsources=<path-to-jar-file>
```

After that, we may add then in a special JBoss file jboss-deployment-structure.xml within META-INF directory:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jetbrains.kotlin" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

Now the jar successfully deploys and works!